# On attempt to back up data, copy and paste fails to copy any files. What is the root cause of this on laptop running Windows XP system?

Tags: filesystems, windows-explorer, copy-paste

Laptop (running XP) fails to start most of the time i try to boot it (last 20 times). Tried it again tonight, it started. Bought an external hard disk to backup required data a few days ago in case laptop started up. It recognised new hardware and showed the drive in explorer. However copy and paste of directories or a single file to the drive fails. Copy and paste on local drives fails also. I tried opening a file on local drive and then used save as to copy to external drive. That worked. So what piece am I missing within the system that allows me to copy and paste?

Another symptom are a lot of services won't start.

Answer (score 2):

What is the error message you get when trying to paste?

An alternative to try is to use xcopy from a cmd prompt, i.e.

> Start / Run / CMD.exe
>
> xcopy c:\somedir e:\somedir /e/s

I would copy critical, irreplaceable files, then try a scandisk on the disk (Properites on the drive, then Tools)

Make sure you have a good antivirus program running that is up to date.